# Doctrine DQL stop eager loading one to many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Using Doctrine I would like to only return an object and a few left joins.

But, for some reason, Doctrine (using DQL) just keeps loading all my data.

```
class User {

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NAMESPACE\Entity\TeamUserGroup", mappedBy="user")
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $groups;

}
```

And Then, TeamUserGroup again has many-to-one's:

```
class TeamUserGroup {

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NAMESPACE\AuthBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="groups")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 *
 * @var User
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NAMESPACE\TeamBundle\Entity\Team", inversedBy="groups")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 *
 * @var Team
 */
private $team;

}
```

This is my DQL:

```
public function fetchUser()
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s')
        ->andWhere('s.email=(:email)')
        ->addSelect('groups')->leftJoin('s.groups', 'groups')
        ->setParameter('email', $parameterBag['email']);

    try {
        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException $exception) {
    }

}
```

And for some reason Doctrine just loads EVERY association.

So I have this structure:

```
// User Object
    // All my Groups
        // All the Teams of that Group
            // All the Users in that team ...
```

How can I stop this (so I just get my Object and the left-join).
This is my wanted result:

```
// User Object
    // All my Groups
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue based on the provided code example. What is the executed SQL query from the Symfony Profiler? The eager loading issue generally only occurs when you have a bidirectional `OneToOne` association and query against the inverse side. [[sic](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4389)] or that the script is calling the Lazy Loaded field elsewhere, which would show another database query when Lazy Loaded. The later is the case when I recreated your example.

Comment: Voting to close this question since the provided code is not able to reproduce the issue described. Please update your question with some additional context from your actual code, so that we can correctly identify the cause.